# Customise logo on Allure report generated in TeamCity

Tags: c#, teamcity, specflow, allure

I am using the TeamCity Allure plugin to generate reports for some SpecFlow tests. I am looking for a way to customise the report (i.e. change the default logo, title etc.). I couldn't find any information on how to do this for  reports generated in TeamCity. What do I need to modify to change the logo ? Any information greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer, posting it for anyone who might be searching for this. You can find the custom logo plugin files under TeamCity\buildAgent\tools\allure-commandline\allure-x.x.x\plugins\custom-logo-plugin\static. In there you can provide the new logo and customise the css as outlined in the allure documentation.